# Visual Studio 11 "Target Framework" keep reverting to 4

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Every time I open some website with VS 11 the "Target Framework" is being reset to version 4.0, even if I've changed it before to 4.5.
[image]

Is it a known bug?

Comment: I am having this same issue right now. Not a website, just an old 4.0 project. Wanting to retarget it. It just pops back to 4.0 after I confirm the 'modify project file' prompt.

Comment: @payo I've found the solution: backup your sln file, open it using a text editor and search for places where 4.0 framework is determined and replace it with 4.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

modifying the sln file solved it

Comment: I was concerned there could be other fields I was leaving out that VS would auto create for me.